# Calling unmanaged code from a C# thread

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, dll, managed

I have an unmanaged C++ library for which I've created a managed C++ wrapper.  I'm now trying to call this from C#.  So far so good.  However when I try to call the same code from within in a C# thread I get exceptions from within the unmanaged code:

Expression: vector subscript out of range

Is this even possible?  I'm assuming each thread would get it's own instance of the unmanaged class?

I've searched long and hard for more information on calling unmanaged code from within threads but info seems sparce to say the least.

Thanks in advance for any help

C++ Wrapper

```
// Managed wrapper
public ref class EllipseFit
{
   private:
       // Pointer to unmanaged class
   UnmanagedEllipseFit* _unmanagedEllipseFit;

   public:

       // Constructor & Destructor
   EllipseFit() 
   {
       _unmanagedEllipseFit = new UnmanagedEllipseFit();
       }

   ~EllipseFit() 
   { 
       delete _unmanagedEllipseFit; 
   }

       List<Ellipse^>^ ProcessImage(array<Byte>^ image, int width, int height)
       { 
           pin_ptr<unsigned char> pimg = &image[0];
       _unmanagedEllipseFit->processsImage(pimg, width, height); 

           // Marshal the results... <edited>
       return ellipses;
       }
};
```

C# Thread

```
    private void DcThread()
    {
        EllipseFit ellipseFit = new EllipseFit();

        string fullPath = _fileList.GetNext();
        while (fullPath != null)
        {
            // Load the image
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fullPath);
            byte[] imageData = TsImage.ConvertBitmap(bitmap);

            // Process
            List<DcEllipse> ellipses = ellipseFit.ProcessImage(imageData, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

            // Save the associated text file.. (Debug)
            TextWriter textFile = new StreamWriter(fullPath.Replace(".jpg", ".txt"));
            foreach (DcEllipse ellipse in ellipses)
                textFile.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", ellipse.X, ellipse.Y, ellipse.MajorAxisLength, ellipse.MinorAxisLength, ellipse.Angle));
            textFile.Close();

            fullPath = _fileList.GetNext();
        }
    }
```

C# Thread Start

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(DcThread);
t1.Start();
```

Comment: You're going to have to show some of the C++/CLI code for us to make ANY sense of this.

Comment: * EDIT * The exceptions only occur when I have more than one thread.  In a thread of it;s own with no other threads I don't see any exceptions.

Comment: Are you explicitly creating separate instances of the class for each thread? Sharing either the managed wrapper class or the unmanaged native class when they're not designed for multithreading is a big no-no.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I create a new instance of EllipseFit for each thread.  Apologies for not posting the code upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed types in .NET follow the same rules, no matter whether they're written in C# or C++/CLI.

While it's possible to create a new instance of the C++/CLI class for each thread, it's not going to happen automatically without you telling the compiler that's what you want.

EDIT: Looking at the code, I don't see any problems apart from a memory leak.  The C++/CLI class should have both a destructor and finalizer, like this:

```
!EllipseFit() 
{ 
    delete _unmanagedEllipseFit; 
    _unmanagedElipseFit = nullptr;
}


~EllipseFit() { this->!EllipseFit(); }
```

As for the crash -- perhaps the unmanaged code uses static or global variables, and thus can't be used concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: Hi Ben, I do create an instance of the managed wrapper in each thread. I just can't understand why if each thread has it's own instance I'd be seeing different behaviour when I run more than one thread..

Comment: Ahh now.. a global variable deep within the unmanaged my C++ code seems to have been the problem.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: @user: You probably also want a `using` statement to make sure that the object gets disposed in a timely fashion.